# How to enter elemets in a hashmap and check for the existence of a particular key?

Tags: java

I am trying to read a csv file and storing its contents in a hash map and checking the existence of a particular key in the hash map.

Here is my code,Please let me know where am i wrong because i m ant able to figure out my mistake

```
import java.io.*;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.*;

public class PoolCsv {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Calendar currentdate = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String presdate = dateformat.format(currentdate.getTime());
            currentdate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 4);
            String futdate = dateformat.format(currentdate.getTime());
            System.out.println(presdate);
            System.out.println(futdate);
            String poolcsv = "D:\\pool_items.csv";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(poolcsv));
            String lines = null;
            String[] tokens = null;
            String startdate = null;
            String enddate = null;
            HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
            while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
                tokens = lines.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i <= tokens.length; i++) {
                    startdate = tokens[5];
                    enddate = tokens[6];
                }

                hash.put(startdate, enddate);

                boolean flag = hash.containsKey(presdate);
                if (flag) {
                    System.out.println("value exists");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println(io);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like you are doing: `put` to add elements and `containsKey` to check if a key exists.... What are you asking?

Comment: nothing seems to be working inside the if condition

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean flag = hash.containsKey(presdate);
if(flag){
    System.out.println("value exists");
}
```

This should be `outside the loop` in which you are populating the map.

Comment: Still nothing within the if condition is getting executed

Comment: Are you sure that 'presdate' is in the hash map? It may be possible that your input is in different format or you don't have any input for current date in which case containsKey() should return false.

Comment: Yes, there are entries with present date in the file

Comment: please help me solving this problem

Comment: You can print the contents of hash i.e System.out.println(hash) and see if it contains the key you are looking for. There must be some problem in processing the csv file for example.

Comment: :( all the contents can be printed but i m unable to check the existence of a particular key

Comment: do you see the key in the content that is printed out??

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what do you want to do, but the FOR loop is really rare, you are looping through all the tokens, but getting always positions 5 and 6, so there is no need of a for there, only get those two positions from every token.

```
        while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
            tokens = lines.split(",");
            //I dont think you neeed this for.
            for (int i = 0; i <= tokens.length; i++) {
                startdate = tokens[5];
                enddate = tokens[6];
            }

            hash.put(startdate, enddate);

            boolean flag = hash.containsKey(presdate);
            if (flag) {
                System.out.println("value exists");
            }
        }
```

Maybe you could have some information if you print presdate and startdate to ensure that both Strings have the same format. yyyy-MM-dd (beware the separator) and the Strings are really equal so the ContainsKey can find that key on the map.